# Getting Show Password checkbox instead of Reveal Button

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Trying to add a reveal button to a PasswordBox, but instead getting "Show Password" checkbox.
Using following code:

```
IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled="True"
```

Expected result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSeFr.png

Results in emulator:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FQl8.png

Full PasswordBox code:

`<PasswordBox
    Margin="10,5,10,5"
    x:Name="PasswordLogin"
    Grid.Row="2"
    FontSize="{StaticResource TextStyleExtraLargeFontSize}"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled="True"
    />`

Comment: That's interesting since the `RevealButtonStyle` in the [default style template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj710188.aspx) just has `&#xE052;` from `{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}` set as its text content. So would be curious where that checkbox is coming from. You using any kind of other than default theme/templates?

Comment: @Chris W. I used default Windows Phone template and made a new Blank Page for login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior in windows phone. In Windows it will show icon in the textbox where as in windows phone it will show checkbox below the password box

Comment: It seems that my grid height wasn't big enough to fit both elements and in result I was getting only the Checkbox. Thanks.